# Stop button doesn't stop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a "STOP" button for a program that replaces text into a div every second.

Here's the code:

```
var Timer=setInterval(function(){first()}, 1000);

function first() 
{

    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var notes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
    var quality1 = ["#", "b", " ", " "];

    var randomNotes = notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * notes.length)];
    var randomQuality1 = quality1[Math.floor(Math.random() * quality1.length)];

    var all = randomNotes + randomQuality1;
    letter.innerHTML = all;

    letter.replace("all","all");

}

function stop()
{
    clearInterval(Timer);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", first, false);
```

I'm relatively new to programming, but I can't find a solution!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You do know you can do this: `var Timer = setInterval(first, 1000);`, if you don't have any arguments to pass to your `first` function. Just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. Here is an example of how you could implement it into HTML:

```
<script>
var Timer;
window.onload=function(){Timer=setInterval(function(){first()}, 1000);}

function first(){
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var notes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
    var quality1 = ["#", "b", " ", " "];

    var randomNotes = notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * notes.length)];
    var randomQuality1 = quality1[Math.floor(Math.random() * quality1.length)];

    var all = randomNotes + randomQuality1;
    letter.innerHTML = all;

    letter.replace("all","all");

}
function stop(){
    clearInterval(Timer);
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="STOP"/>
<div id="letter"></div>
```